# Java: ScheduleFuture getClass and get information when run next?

Tags: java, scheduler

i try to get rid of the java scheduler. I am using a ScheduleExecuterService and save the ScheduleFuture object in a Hashtable to get access at a later point. But how can i retrieve the runnableClass from the ScheduleFuture object?

Second question: I like to know when the runnableClass will be run next? But i didnt find a function therefore.

This is my Code:

```
private Hashtable<String,ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduled;
```

...

```
    String id = "RUNID";    
    MyScheduledRunnable runnableClass = new MyScheduledRunnable(log)
    ScheduledFuture<?> s = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableClass, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    scheduled.put(id, s);

... later ...

    ScheduledFuture s = scheduled.get("RUNID");
```

How to get the runnableClass from s?
How to get info's when the job will be run next? e.g. s.nextRun()? 
Or to check if it is still alive?

Maybe some of you can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the runnableClass from s?

I wouldn't expect this to be possible if you didn't explicitly store it.

> How to get info's when the job will be run next? e.g. s.nextRun()?

`ScheduledFuture` extends the `Delayed` interface, which has the [`getDelay(TimeUnit)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html#getDelay(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), which I'd expect to be usable to get the time until the next run.

> Or to check if it is still alive?

The Javadoc of `scheduleAtFixedRate` specifies that the future can only terminate by throwing an exception (which you could retrieve with `get()`), by being cancelled with the `cancel` method (which can be tested using `isCancelled()` or when the executor is terminated (which can be tested using `isTerminated`).

Comment: Thanks, how can i retrieve the exception if one is thrown? Do you have an example plz?

Comment: Just calling get() will throw an ExecutionException; calling getCause on that should return the original exception.